# SQL query to get the sum and the latest enries

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a table called machineStatus:

```
ID  Successfiles totaldata Backupsessiontime
> 1 3   988   1256637314
> 2 21   323   1256551419
> 3 8   23   1256642968
> 4 94   424   1256642968
> 1 42   324   1256810937
> 1 0   433   1256642968
```

Now here i want to group by ID where the successfiles and total data gets summed up, but only display the latest Backupsessiontime.
I can do this seperately but not together.
Any suggestions????

For doing this seperately:

to get the sum:

```
select ID, sum(NumOfSuccessFiles), sum(TotalData)
from MachineStat
 group by ID;
```

to get latest:

```
With idT as (
select ID
from MachineStat
group by ID

) 
select applyT.* 
from idT p
CROSS APPLY (
select top 1 ID,BackupSessionTime from MachineStat where eID=p.ID   
order by MachineID desc
) as applyT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to do

`select ID, sum(NumOfSuccessFiles), sum(TotalData), max(Backupsessiontime)
from MachineStat
group by ID;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregate function that would suit your needs:

```
select
    ID,
    sum(NumOfSuccessFiles) TotalNumOfSuccessFiles,
    sum(TotalData) TotalData,
    max(Backupsessiontime) LastBackupsessiontime
from
    MachineStat ms
group by
    ID
```

Or you can use a sub-query in your primary query, if you need more complicated sorting logic.

```
select
    ID,
    sum(NumOfSuccessFiles) TotalNumOfSuccessFiles,
    sum(TotalData) TotalData,
    (select top 1 Backupsessiontime from MachineStat where ID = ms.ID order by ...) LastBackupsessiontime
from
    MachineStat ms
group by
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Max(BackupSessionTime) ?